# Toggle visibility of a link?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ideally I could publish a message from ROS that would set the transparency of a specified link to any value.

Would I have to write a custom plugin?

---

**Pursuing the gazebojs approach:**

This is using Gazebo 2.2.3

I've gone through

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gazebojs_install&cat=gazebojs

One note is that npm install installs node_modules to the current directory, I moved it to a better location and the require below is the relative path to it::

```
  var gazebojs = require('./npm/node_modules/gazebojs')
  var gazebo = new gazebojs.Gazebo()
  msg = { "parent_name" : "sensor_head", "name" : "sensor_head_rotation_link", "visible":false };
  gazebo.publish('gazebo.msgs.Visual', '~/Visual', msg);
```

But the link stays visible.  Am I missing something else required to turn the visibility off?  I assume leaving out all the optional fields except 'visible' in the protobuf is fine.

If I put garbage into the parent_name or name fields there are no errors.  Am I using those fields incorrectly?  In the World tab I see `Model | sensor_head | sensor_head_rotation_link`, the Property for clicking on that shows the name as  `sensor_head::sensor_head_rotation_link`

(I have it correct above but if the msg has a problem it mostly results in an error that crashes node like::

```
  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'j2pb_error'
    what():  Unknown field: visibility
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

)

---

**Pursuing the C++ Approach:**

If I use the following code, launch gazebo and create a box called unit_box_1, running `./visibility unit_box_1 link` still doesn't produce any visual changes.

visibility.cpp:

```
int main(int argn, char** argv)
{
  gazebo::setupClient(argn, argv);

  std::string name = "sensor_head_rotation_link";
  std::string parent_name = "sensor_head";

  if (argn >= 3)
  {
    parent_name = argv[1];
    name = argv[2];
  }

  gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node());
  node->Init();

  // gztopic echo /gazebo/default/visual shows this 
  gazebo::transport::PublisherPtr pub =
      node->Advertise<gazebo::msgs::Visual>("~/visual");

  std::cout << "waiting for connection" << std::endl;
  pub->WaitForConnection();

  double transparency = 1.0;
  bool visible = true;

  gazebo::msgs::Visual msg; 
  msg.set_parent_name(parent_name);
  msg.set_name(name);
  std::cout << "parent " << parent_name << ", name " << name << std::endl;

  while (true)
  {
    msg.set_transparency(transparency);
    msg.set_visible(visible);
    //std::cout << "transparency " << transparency << std::endl;
    pub->Publish(msg);

    visible = !visible;
    transparency = 1.0 - transparency;

    sleep(2.0);
  }

  gazebo::shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7637/toggle-visibility-of-a-link?/) by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use Gazebo's transport mechanism to publish a visual message to toggle visibility.

Topic: `~/visual`

Message Type: [gazebo::msgs::Visual](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/msg-api/4.0.0/visual_8proto.html)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2014-12-05**:
Is GazeboJS the quickest way to do that as described on http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gazebojs_pubsub&cat=gazebojs  ?(python would be nice, I did see http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19/publish-a-topic/ but it looks inferior)

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-12-08**:
gazebojs would work, or you'd can use the gazebo transport mechansim in a C program.

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2014-12-19**:
I've updated the question above with problems encountered in the gazebojs appraoch.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-12-30**:
The field is called `visible`, not `visibility`. See the [visual.proto API here](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/msg-api/4.0.0/visual_8proto.html)

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2014-12-30**:
Yes, as already noted the wrong field name crashes it, the correct name doesn't crash but didn't produce a visual change.

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2015-01-06**:
I tried out the publishing to ~/visual in a C++ program and could not get a a change to visibility with either visible or transparency.  The code is in the updated description above.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try setting the `transparency` field to 0.0 to make it not visible or 1.0 to make it visible. I have used this successfully before (see [DRCVehiclePlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/7aee32718c4a74419b2bb447ab41d8ab9e4edf68/drcsim_gazebo_plugins/src/DRCVehiclePlugin.cc?at=default#cl-369)). Note that I did set both the name and parent name.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-12-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2015-01-06**:
Have you tried the GazeboJS method?  Transparency doesn't work for me either.

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2015-01-06**:
If C/C++ is the only method that works I'll try that out, https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/raw/default/examples/stand_alone/publisher can probably be adapted.